# Azure Web App files encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-web-app-service

It's very easy to activate encryption on *SQL Azure* and *Azure Storage Account*.
But what about the *Web App* files folder ?

- Is the `D:\home` folder natively encrypted ?
- If not, Is it possible to activate encryption explicitly ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no encryption option currently on Web App storage. If that's needed, you'd need to work with one of the services that supports encryption (e.g. blob storage) or encrypt/decrypt yourself via your app.